# What is Mastery In Reviewing?

Tags: jhana

The books and videos all describe it as,

**Looking at jhana and its factors in retrospective knowledge**

What does this mean exactly? Is it going over the events that happened during the jhana?  there anything specific you suppose to do?

Comment: Suttas have the phrase "Knowledge and vision of things as they are", in the *Supporting Conditions* I think. This would necessarily be knowledge of things that have happened, how they come about (cause and effect), thus: 'retrospective', as opposed to seeing what will happen.

Answer (score 1):

I think you go over the meditation, what you did, how, compare with other meditation sessions to find out how to easily get jhana.

I did this and this and I got that result and the other time I did that and that and got another result.

So in time you get better at recognizing the factors and how to get in jhana.